# Google Sheets: Change of the formula results to numeric format or to percentage

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to change the value counted by formula to the number format or to the percentage.

Currently, I'm using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3), "", IF(AND(K3="",L3="",M3="",N3="",O3=""),"1", "0"))
```

And basically, it returns **1** when all of the cells in the formula are empty or it returns **0** when one of the cells is not empty. Also, it leaves the cell empty, if the cell A is not empty.

When I want to change the format of 1 or 0 to percentage or to number through the Google Sheets interface, it doesn't work. Any idea how to add it to the formula to make the results numeric?

Note:
I also tested the following formula, but the system just doesn't see the result as a percentage or number:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3), "", IF(AND(K3="",L3="",M3="",N3="",O3=""),"100%", "0%"))
```

Comment: Remove double quote from numbers `=IF(ISBLANK(A3), "", IF(AND(K3="",L3="",M3="",N3="",O3=""),1, 0))`

Comment: @Harun24hr ah I can't believe it was that easy, post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quote from numbers. Try-

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3), "", IF(AND(K3="",L3="",M3="",N3="",O3=""),1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(A3="",, IF((K3="")*(L3="")*(M3="")*(N3="")*(O3=""), 1, 0))
```